# Relationship between models are right but Controller can't find any records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, routes, controller

I have a `Payment`, `Client` and `PaymentTransactions` model. I'm trying to show all `PaymentTransactions` for a given `Client` but the controller returns an empty array.

The route I'm using to get there is `/api/v1/clients/:id/payment_transactions`

This is my Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :payments, only: [ :index ]
      resources :clients, only: [ :index ]

      resources :clients, only: [:show] do
        resources :payment_transactions, only: [:index]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rails routes:

```
Uri Pattern /api/v1/clients/:client_id/payment_transactions
Controller#Action api/v1/payment_transactions#index {:format=>:json}
```

These are my models:

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, optional: true, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :payment_transactions, dependent: :destroy
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payment, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :payment_transactions, through: :payment, dependent: :destroy
end

class PaymentTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :payment, optional: true
  has_one :client, through: :payment
end
```

And this is my controller:

```
class Api::V1::PaymentTransactionsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_action :set_client

  def index
    @transactions = PaymentTransaction.where(client: @client)
  end

  private

  def set_client
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  end
end
```

I can do `PaymentTransaction.client` and get the Client associated to that PaymentTransaction. I can do `Client.payment_transactions` to get all transactions for the given Client as well.

However, making a call to `/api/v1/clients/1/payment_transactions` returns `[]`.

EDIT:

A change in the controller action to `@transactions = PaymentTransaction.where(client_id: @client.id)` resulted in

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column payment_transactions.client_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...transactions".* FROM "payment_transactions" WHERE "payment_t...
                                                             ^
):
    1: json.array! @transactions do |transaction|
    2:   json.extract! transaction, :id, :payment_id, :transaction_identification, :amount, :status
    3: end
```

Comment: Just do `@transactions = Payment transaction.where(client_id: @client.id)` or `@transactions = @client.payment_transactions`

Comment: Thanks! @Maxence. The later worked. First one resulted in the error I added to the OP.

Comment: My mistake. PaymentTransaction model has no client_id column. The latter should work.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord's `where` method expects its input to be columns on the called model, so you can't use it to filter by intermediate associations. Instead, you can call the defined `payment_transaction` asosciation directly from the `@client` object.

```rb
  def index
    @transactions = @client.payment_transactions
  end
```

*Side note:*
Using the association directly has the added advantage of allowing you to eager load the records later on, in case you ever need to list clients alongside their payment transactions. e.g.

```rb
Client.all.includes(:payment_transactions)
```

Using a `where` won't make this easily doable.